# ActiveRecord .where() method ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a weird issue... In a model User, that has no relation with the model Interest, I try to call this query:

```
# file model.rb
def self.my_func
    Interest.where('id IN (?)', [1,2])
end
```

But it's completely ignored... and if I replace by this:

```
# file model.rb
def self.my_func
    Interest.find(1)
end
```

the .find() method is triggered and I get result.

If I directly call `Interest.where('id IN (?)', [1,2])` in `rails console` it works...
I'm on RoR 3.2.13

Any idea?
Thank you all.

Comment: Are you iterating or calling `#to_a` against `my_func`?

Comment: What is returned from my_func? I don't understand "completely ignored."

Comment: What do you *do* with the results of the function?

Comment: By ignored I mean that in the console, I don't see the query at all.
And if I call a .find() instead of .where() (in the same context), I see the query in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails doesn't *evaluate* the query until you actually try to access the results. Calling `Model.where` just returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` onto which you can chain additional `where`/`order`/etc calls.

Try this (`.all` forces the query to be evaluated and returns an array of results):

```
def self.my_func
  Interest.where(id: [1,2]).all
end
```

Note that should shouldn't actually do this. It's much better for your model to just allow the `ActiveRecord::Relation` to be returned from the method, so the calling code can apply additional scoping/ordering methods to it.

Also note that, instead of manually building an `id in (?)` query, Rails is smart enough to do it for you if you just use `where(id: [1,2])`.

---

Bonus notes:

On the terminal, the results get evaluated from `Model.where` immediately because IRB invokes `inspect` on the result of each expression you enter so it has something to print, and the returned `ActiveRecord::Relation` evaluates its query when inspected. You can bypass this to prove the point to yourself by adding `;nil`, so that your statement evaluates to `nil`; note that the `SELECT` doesn't happen until I manually call `x.inspect`:

```
irb(main):008:0> x = User.where("name like 'bob'"); nil
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> x.inspect
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (name like 'bob')
=> "[]"
```

Comment: Yes! You saved me lot of time! I didn't know that the query isn't executed until I try to access result. Thank you soooo much !